# C# 7 Use Pattern Matching not working

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

what am I missing here.

Visual Studio tells me to use inline pattern matching and re-writes the code for me but when it does I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS8121  An expression of type TReturnState cannot be handled by a pattern of type LightState.   DataModels  C:\Users\Michael\Documents\windows\GCMS UWP\Models\Models\Elements\Lights\Light.cs  77  Active

Here is the original code:

```
    public override void UpdateState<TReturnState>(TReturnState returnState)
    {
        var newState = returnState as LightState;

        if (newState != null)
            State = newState;

        base.UpdateState(returnState);
    }
```

And here is what it looks like when VS redoes it for me.

```
    public override void UpdateState<TReturnState>(TReturnState returnState)
    {
        if (returnState is LightState newState)
            State = newState;

        base.UpdateState(returnState);
    }
```

I prefer the adjusted way but I am getting the error.  Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Packages I am using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.3.1",
    "Newtonsoft.Json": "9.0.1",
    "System.ValueTuple": "4.3.0"
  },
```

Comment: `State = (LightState)newState;`

Comment: @SirRufo how is it useless it updates a global variable called "State"?

Comment: @Hogan Oops, you are right ... :o)

Comment: @Hogan  I get an error with that also... AND Visual Studio tells me it's unnecessary cast.

Comment: Maybe you hit https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16195

Comment: The original code works, it's the variations of it that's giving errors.  Any attempt to simplify it, even when VisualStudio tells me to, gives a compile error.

Comment: @SirRufo  I think you're right.  I have added a comment on there as well.  Thank you.  Looks like a bug.

Comment: Looks like due to a bug that @SirRufo pointed out I have to do a cast to object for now.  Which Visual Studio also tells me is unnecessary and attempts to fix it.  Ugh...  So much for complete solution refactoring with this kinda mess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @SirRufo pointed out in a comment it appears to be a known bug in C# 7.

The fix was to write the code with cast to an object.

```
    public override void UpdateState<TReturnState>(TReturnState returnState)
    {
        if ((object)returnState is SpeakerState newState)
            State = newState;

        base.UpdateState(returnState);
    }
```

However; this isn't a REAL fix but a hack to get past the bug.  Visual Studio also tells me that this cast to object is unnecessary and attempts to fix it but when it does I get the error again.

This puts a dampening on full code refactoring via Visual Studio.

[Link to known issue posted by Sir Rufo.](http://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/16195)

**Edit:  Upgrading to C# 7.1 fixes this issue of boxing for pattern matching anonymous types and it now works like it's supposed to without the overhead.**

Comment: Used your method but didn't work for me, also update Visual Studio to 15.3.5 version didn't work

Comment: @MohammadSadeghipour Upgrade to C# 7.1.  It now properly pattern matches anonymous types like it's supposed to.

Comment: I did what you said but it's still not working with the following error:
error CS1617: Invalid option '7.1' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, Default or an integer in range 1 to 6.

Comment: Can you post the code and let me see it?  It's working for me any several situations.

Comment: Never mind actually, I got it fixed by adding Microsoft.Net.Compilers NuGet package to my project.